# Codeigniter JavaScript issue when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have this form in my view

```
<form name="login" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>households/filter" id="contactForm" method="POST">
                <span class="search-options search-field">
                    <select id="city" name="city" class="filter-field">
                        <option selected="" value="-1">
                        <?php echo $this->lang->line("Filter By City");?>     
                        </option>
                        <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option><option value="Madrid">Madrid</option><option value="Valencia">Valencia</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
</form>
```

and here is the JavaScript for submiting the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'city' );
            urlmenu.onchange = function() {
                 var myform = document.getElementById('contactForm');
                 myform.submit();
        };
     });
```

but it not sending anything to the POST 
My controller is like

```
function filter() {
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    exit;
}
```

Can you help me, why am I getting

```
boolean false
```

Comment: try `$_POST`, or `$this->input->post('field name');`

Comment: `$this->input->post()` :

The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

Comment: With $this->input->post() you take all the data inside the post! but the problem is that the post has nothing inside!!

Comment: Are you sure you have no Javascript errors? Check console.

Comment: no problem at all in js

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but its too long for it, try this code I use it for exactly same thing I guess.

**note that I use bootstrap**

HTML

```
<form action="localhost/etc" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal">                      
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Language</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="language" class="language" id="admin-category">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Moonlanguage</option>
                <option value="2">English</option>
                <option value="3">Deutsch</option>
            </select>                               
        </div>
    </div>                      
</form>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('#admin-category.language').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

The most importatnt parts are `id` and `class` of a `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference that function like that, or iterate through it.

You need to provide an index, e.g. `$this->input->post('field_name')`.

If you want to access all post data, you can use the `$_POST` variable.

**Edit:**

In CI 2.1+ you can do the following.

```
$data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // Returns all POST items with XSS filter
$data = $this->input->post();           // Returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

Comment: Yes i know that, and if you can see thats what i am doing! the problem is that is not sending the post data

Comment: @cbour Read my answer. **You can't use `var_dump($this->input->post());`**

Comment: that's not true `var_dump($this->input->post());` will dump all post simillar to `$_POST`

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: Var_dump saws everything inside the post

Comment: CI 2.1+ this is how i debug all my POST process, it is getting `boolean false` because a post was never initiated. `myform.submit();` never submitted the form.

Comment: Odd, I've had this issue before and the above was what resolved it. I'm not sure what version of CI it was on. Does `$_POST` also return nothing?

Comment: @cbour on your console try looking at the network tab when posting, it will give you a hint what happened to the action

Comment: I think you are not submitting the form at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('city').onchange( function(){ 
        document.getElementById('contactForm').submit();
    }); 
 });

function filter() {
    echo $this->input->post('city');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use predifined form methods in codeigniter:

```
<?php $attr = array('name'=>'login', 'id=>'contactForm');?>
<?php echo form_open('households/filter', $attr);?>
```

instead of your form syntax:

```
<form name="login" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>households/filter" id="contactForm" method="POST">
```

**base_url** is used to add external entities such as images, scripts, or css to the page.

**site_url** is used specify a controller in codeigniter.

in **form_open()** method there is no need to use **site_url**, the first parameter is automatically treated as controller....

for submission via jquery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post("<?php echo site_url('households/filter');?>",
      {
          city: $('#city').val()
      },
      function(response)
      {
         //ajax response area
      });
   });
```